# heatmap: each column with different color and scaling in R/Python

Tags: python-3.x, ggplot2

[image]
I want to generate the annotated heatmap where each column will be having new color.

````
 <my code>
 ```
 import seaborn as sns
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 df = pd.DataFrame({'clust': ['Clust 10','Clust 11','Clust 1','Clust 2','Clust 10','Clust 11','Clust 1','Clust 2','Clust 10','Clust 11','Clust 1','Clust 2'],'value': [4,2,0,0, 0,0,1,3, 1,0,0,0], 'category':  ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C']})
 result = df.pivot(index='clust', columns='category',values='value')
 sns.heatmap(result, annot=True, fmt="g", cmap='viridis')
 plt.show()
 ```

 <Input file>
       No     A     B     C
 Clust 10     4     0     1
 Clust 11     2     0     0
 Clust 1      0     1     0
 Clust 2      0     3     0
 Clust 3      3     1     0
 Clust 4      2     0     2

 <Output>
 enter image description here
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a heat map by plotly module in python. Below is the code which will generate heatmap.

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

a = [
[4, 0, 1],
[2, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0],
[0, 3, 0],
[3, 1, 0],
[2, 0, 2]
]


fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(a)
fig.show()
```

See https://plot.ly/python/annotated-heatmap/ for more information on how to generate heatmap.

Note: I have not tested it but this code is for reference.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I need All column with different colors (please see the uploaded image). If column 1 is yellow, whole column will have variation of yellow (according to the value). Col2: green. Variation of green in column. and so on. 
Thanks

Comment: This is not a code writing place. If you are facing any errors with your code then this is the place where you can take help. We cant write code for you. Read the link and modify what color you want, search for "Custom Text and X & Y Labels" in the link provided

Comment: I made the heatmap using seabon. But I don't get any clue which can change color column wise. I have updated my code.

Comment: by looking at https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html?highlight=heatmap#seaborn.heatmap you can change color with sns.axes_style("white"):

Comment: @Visvanath Polaki. Thanks it working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Working code.

````
 ```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import seaborn as sns
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 df = pd.DataFrame({'clust': ['Clust 10','Clust 11','Clust 1','Clust 2','Clust 10','Clust 11','Clust 1','Clust 2','Clust 10','Clust 11','Clust 1','Clust 2'],'value': [4,2,0,0, 0,0,1,3, 1,0,0,0], 'category':  ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C']})
 result = df.pivot(index='clust', columns='category',values='value')
 print(result)

 cm = ['Blues', 'Greens', 'YlG']
 f, axs = plt.subplots(1, df.columns.size, gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0})
 for i, (s, a, c) in enumerate(zip(result.columns, axs, cm)):
     sns.heatmap(np.array([result[s].values]).T, yticklabels=result.index, xticklabels=[s], annot=True, fmt='.2f', ax=a, cmap=c, cbar=False)
     if i>0:
         a.yaxis.set_ticks([])
 plt.show()
 ```
````